Problem programmatically adding arFragment in an android module used in react native app
I am writing a native android module for my react native app.
When I run the app, i can see the react native's gray root view, inside it i can see the red linear layout and inside it the green frame layout is visible. Also the camera turns on (i can hear the sound and see the phone indicator light for the camera). But no ArFragment is visible, there is no camera feed, although i can see logs from my native module according to which everything is created and working fine.
This is my code:
 
    class MyNativeModule(private val reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) :
SimpleViewManager\<LinearLayout\>() {

        private val savedReactContext: ReactApplicationContext = reactContext
        private var fragmentAdded: Boolean = false;
    
        override fun getName(): String {
            return "MyNativeModule"
        }
    
        override fun createViewInstance(reactContext: ThemedReactContext): LinearLayout {
            val layout = LinearLayout(reactContext)
            layout.id = View.generateViewId()
            layout.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            layout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
            layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#AA0000"))
    
            // Create a FrameLayout to hold the ARFragment
            val fragmentContainer = FrameLayout(reactContext)
            fragmentContainer.id = View.generateViewId()
            fragmentContainer.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            fragmentContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00AA00"))
            layout.addView(fragmentContainer)    
               
            val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
            val arFragment = MyArFragment() // Custom ArFragment
            handler.postDelayed({
                //sendEvent(reactContext, layout.id, "onFireText", "hello world")
                val fragmentManager: FragmentManager =
                    (reactContext.currentActivity as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager
                val fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                
                fragmentTransaction.add(
                    fragmentContainer.id,
                    arFragment as androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
                )
                Log.d("MyArFragment", "AR Fragment added to fragmentContainer.")
                fragmentTransaction.commitNow()
    
            }, 1000)
    
            return layout
        }
    }
    
    class MyArFragment : ArFragment() {
        override fun getSessionConfiguration(session: Session): Config {
            val config = Config(session)
            config.planeFindingMode = Config.PlaneFindingMode.HORIZONTAL_AND_VERTICAL
            return config
        }
    
        override fun onResume() {
            super.onResume()
            Log.d("MyArFragment", "AR Fragment resumed")
        }
    
        override fun onPause() {
            super.onPause()
            Log.d("MyArFragment", "AR Fragment paused")
        }
    
        override fun onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy()
            Log.d("MyArFragment", "AR Fragment destroyed")
        }
    }


And in my react native app:

    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
        <View
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            width: 400,
            height: 800,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: '#ff00ff',
            backgroundColor: '#777777',
            zIndex: 1,
          }}>
          {cameraPermission && (
            <MyNativeModule
              style={{flex: 1, zIndex: 100}}
              onFireText={handleOnFireText}
            />
          )}
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );



In my AndroidManifest.xml i have:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="required" />

And in build.gradle:
implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.46.0'
implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.17.1'

